# Flask python manage.py db upgrade raise error

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on an flask project which contains a lot of models and some of them make use of `from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB`. From management, I created manage.py as per this [link](http://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). `python manage.py init & python manage.py migrate`
are working fine but when I run `python manage.py upgrade` the following error occurs in migrated file.

```
    sa.Column('images', postgresql.JSONB(astext_type=Text()), nullable=True),
    NameError: global name 'Text' is not defined
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Using `sa.Text` instead of `Text`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import that `Text`

As i searched it comes from `sqlalchemy.types`, so you need at the top of file import it

```
from sqlalchemy.types import Text
```

But you don't even need to supply `astext_type` as a parameter, because it defaults to `Text()`. From [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON.params.astext_type) of `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON`:

> **`astext_type`**
>
> the type to use for the `JSON.Comparator.astext` accessor on indexed attributes. Defaults to `types.Text`.

And `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB` is

> Bases: `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.json.JSON`

Comment: @HSL i suggest you post another question with your question, maybe there is some specifics, you can also add this question/answer as a reference (problem research).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54409817/error-alembic-env-name-text-is-not-defined-upon-python-manage-py-db-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Alembic](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic), this is fixed in [0.9.0](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/changelog.html#change-ea3e7edb9b96fbcd3b98dba50ab938c9)